# mysql passwordless local backup/ remote restore

Tags: mysql

I am trying to backup local database and restore it on remote server without showing passwords

```
mysqldump -u local_user -pPWD my_db | mysql -u remote_user -pPWD -h IP -C T
```

, but first, I need to login and created a database to restore to on remote server:

```
mysql -u remote_user -pPWD -h IP -e "create database T;"
```

I've created extra.my.cnf on both, local server A and remote server B.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   37 Aug 14 11:35 extra.my.cnf  <----- A
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 75 Aug 14 18:49 extra.my.cnf    <----- B
```

Content of the remote extra.my.cnf (on B):

```
# cat extra.my.cnf
[client]
user=remote_user
password="PWD"

[mysqldump]
user=remote_user
password="PWD"
```

Using --defaults-extra-file does not work.

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=/path/to/extra.my.cnf -h IP

Could not open required defaults file: /path/to/extra.my.cnf
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
```

What am I missing???

Comment: _"Could not open required defaults file: /path/to/extra.my.cnf"_ - sure that's not just a file permission issue?

Comment: even if set remote file permissions to 777, I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using mysql_config_editor and issue was resolved